# Display remote page's content in full

Tags: php, html, css

I need to fetch a remote page, modify some elements (using 'PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser' library for that) and output modified content.

There's a problem with remote pages that don't have full URLs in their source, so CSS elements and images are not loaded. Sure, it doesn't stop me from modifying elements, but the output looks bad.

For example, open https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/

However, if you use code

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads');
echo $html;
```

it will look bad. I tried to apply a simple hack, but that helps just a little:

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads');
$html=str_ireplace("</head>", "<base href='http://www.raspberrypi.org'></head>", $html);
echo $html;
```

Is there any way to "instruct" script to parse all links from $html variable from 'http://www.raspberrypi.org'? In other words, how to make raspberrypi.org to be the "main" source of all images/CSS elements fetched?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since only Nikolay Ganovski offered a solution, I wrote a code which converts partial pages into full by looking for incomplete css/img/form tags and making them full. In case someone needs it, find the code below:

```
// finalizes remote page by completing incomplete css/img/form URLs (path/file.css becomes http://somedomain.com/path/file.css, etc.)
function finalize_remote_page($content, $root_url)
{
    $root_url_without_scheme = preg_replace('/(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(.*)\/?$/i', '$1', $root_url); // ignore schemes, in case URL provided by user was http://somedomain.com while URL in source is https://somedomain.com (or vice-versa)

    $content_object = str_get_html($content);
    if (is_object($content_object))
    {
        foreach ($content_object->find('link.[rel=stylesheet]') as $entry) //find css
        {
            if (substr($entry->href, 0, 2) != "//" && stristr($entry->href, $root_url_without_scheme) === FALSE) // ignore "invalid" URLs like // somedomain.com
            {
                $entry->href = $root_url.$entry->href;
            }
        }
        foreach ($content_object->find('img') as $entry) //find img
        {
            if (substr($entry->src, 0, 2) != "//" && stristr($entry->src, $root_url_without_scheme) === FALSE) // ignore "invalid" URLs like // somedomain.com
            {
                $entry->src = $root_url.$entry->src;
            }
        }
        foreach ($content_object->find('form') as $entry) //find form
        {
            if (substr($entry->action, 0, 2) != "//" && stristr($entry->action, $root_url_without_scheme) === FALSE) // ignore "invalid" URLs like // somedomain.com
            {
                $entry->action = $root_url.$entry->action;
            }
        }
    }
    return $content_object;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just have tried this on local, and I've noticed(in the source code) the link tags in the HTML are like this:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/wp-content/themes/mind-control/js/qtip/jquery.qtip.min.css' />
```

It obviously requires a file that should be in my local directory (like localhost/wp-content/etc.../).
The href of the link tags must be something like

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://www.raspberrypi.org/wp-content/themes/mind-control/js/qtip/jquery.qtip.min.css' />
```

So what you probably want to do is find all link tags and add in their href attribute "https://www.raspberrypi.org/" in front of the rest.

EDIT: Hey I've actually made the style work, try this code:

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads');
$i = 0;
foreach($html->find('link') as $element)
{
       $html->find('link', $i)->href = 'http://www.raspberrypi.org'.$element->href;
       $i++;
}
echo $html;die;
```

Comment: Yes, it looks like a working solution (which will require some extra coding) - finding every "invalid" link that doesn't contain remote domain's inside it, adding domain and outputting the content

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, it seems like the only solution now. Of course, I will need to modify code a bit (to add prefix only to links without domain URL because the code will be used to parse many different pages), but most likely this will be the accepted answer (unless someone comes with some even easier idea) :)

Comment: Yes you can check if the href contains the domain . For the images I suggest to iterate through the body elements and check if the string value of the whole element contains an image extension(like '.gif', '.png'). Then you can edit the current element's image url or src, whatever it is.